# User cleanup in Sharepoint 2010?

Tags: user-profile, user-profile-service

In our project, User accounts are set to be inactive in Active directory whenever they depart and it will be removed permanently only after 6months.

In this case, may I expect that SharePoint User profile clean up job takes care of the profile removal ? or should I need to run the "Remove-SPUser 'Contoso\jdoe' –web siteURL" cmdlet?

Comment: What will happen if a user's profile is set to be disabled and moved to the disabled OU(just another OU)? does SharePoint deletes the user profile and properties?

Comment: As long as the disabled OU is not in the imported group, they will be removed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to setup Exclusion Filters for User Profile Synchronization in SharePoint to check for the 'disabled' flag on the Active Directory account.  Then those accounts should be handled automatically.

Specifically, to not synchronize disabled AD accounts, you set to exclude:

```
userAccountControl Bit on equals 2
```

More info on that [is here](http://www.harbar.net/archive/2011/02/22/323.aspx).